# Typescript constraint the template

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created this `HashMap` interface:

```
export interface HashMap<K, V> {
    [name: K]: V;
}
```

With the idea that I can use it as:

```
const map: HashMap<String, String>;
```

However, right now I get an error saying `name` can only be of type `string` or `number`.

How do I apply the constraint on `K` template here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not use the UpperCase primitive type names. That is to say use `string` instead of `String`.

As to the meat of your question, a TypeScript index signature's parameter type must be one of `string`, `number`, or `symbol`. The last is only available under `--target es2015` or greater.

You can, however, constraint the type of the key to be a subset of string values. In this case you must use a `type` alias declaration, not an `interface`.

```
export type HashMap<K extends string, V> = {
  [P in K]?: V;
}
```

The `[P in K]` syntax means "enumerate each string literal type in the subset of string types with which `K` is instantiated".

This is useful because we can restrict the contents of the map by specifying a union type with string literal types as its constituents.

For example:

```
const map: HashMap<'firstName' | 'lastName', string> = {
  firstName: 'John', // OK
  nickname: 'Johnny' // Error
};
```

Basically, for all intents and purposes you must use string but you can constrain the key type to be a specific string or a set of specific strings by using a union type.

In practice, the string union type will very often be a function of another type.

For example:

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}


interface PropertyMetadata {
  kind: 'data' | 'accessor';
}

type LazyItem = {
  [P in keyof Item]: PropertyDescriptor
};
```

`keyof` is a Type Operator that takes a type and returns a type that is the string union of its property keys.

---

Now, this is probably not what you are looking for. If you want to use an arbitrary key type, bound by some constraint you will need to use an ES2015 `Map` object. Prior to the addition of this type in JavaScript, it was not possible to perform this mapping in a clean way and `string` was essentially the only viable key type.

By combining an ES2015 map with the power of TypeScript generics (templates as you call them) we can approximate what you are looking for.

For example:

```
interface Category {
  name: string;
  products: Product[];
}

interface Product {
  name: string;
  category: Category;
}

const categoriesToProducts = new Map<Category, Product[]>();

declare function getProducts(): Product[];

const products = getProducts();

products.forEach(product => {
  const mapped = categoriesToProducts.get(product.category);
  if (mapped) {
    mapped.push(product);
  } 
  else {
    categoriesToProducts.add(product.category, [product]);
  }
});
```

Comment: But I want to do `HashMap<string, string>` not `HashMap<'key', string>`. I basically want to have both `HashMap<string, ...>` and `HashMap<number, ...>`

Comment: @Kousha I updated showing how an ES2015 map can accomplish this and how TypeScript generics can enforce it. JavaScript and therefore TypeScript are very string oriented. On standard Objects, `number` subscripts are actually converted to `string`s by JavaScript runtimes before lookup is performed. This even happens for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only types you can normally use as keys for [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) are primitive types `string` and `number`, I don't think there is much gained from the ability to parametrize on them, but if you insist...

```
type IndexableTypes<V> = {
    [s: string]: { [n: string]: V };
    number: { [n: number]: V };
}

type SN = { [n: number]: 'number', [s: string]: string };


type HashMap<K extends string | number, V> = IndexableTypes<V>[SN[K]];

const map: HashMap<string, string> = {}; // inferred as {[n: string]: string; }
const map1: HashMap<number, string> = {}; // inferred as  {[n: number]: string;}

const map2: HashMap<number, HashMap<string, number>> = {};
// inferred as  
{[n: number]: 
  {[n: string]: number;};
}

const map4: HashMap<boolean, {}> = {};
// error: Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number'.
```

However, you could just use es2015 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class if it's available in your runtime:

```
type MyMap<K extends string | number, V> = Map<K, V>
```

Comment: No I just want to have string or number, but allow the user to choose which they use for the key.

Comment: ok then, by sheer luck it seems that's possible. I updated the answer.

Comment: That is really interesting but it does not prevent someone from using a number (unquoted) as a key to access the `map: HashMap<string, string>` variable.